# AWS Spectrum vs Athena proper JSON format for multi row data

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Hey I am trying to ingest/query some JSON data using AWS Spectrum.

I have created a json which format looks like (every row in a single line):

```
{"name": "name1", "attr":"someval"},
{"name": "name2", "attr":"someval2"}
```

It is not a valid JSON format, but the Glue AWS crawler detects the columns properlyt. Queries also in Athena do run, but in Spectrum I get a invalid syntax error

```
Task failed due to an internal error. Error occured during Ion/JSON extractor match: IERR_INVALID_SYNTAX
```

I am wondering how to get my JSON data (which is basically an array) into a format so AWS Glue Crawler will detect all the columns and Athena and Spectrum can query it. Have done some try and error but for example a valid JSON representation does not detect the columns properly in Glue and the data catalog:

```
[{"name": "name1", "attr":"someval"},
{"name": "name2", "attr":"someval2"}]
```

any advice?

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried not to include comma (`,`) at the end for the line in the first example?

Comment: tried that and fed up with trial and error. seems like the glue crawler is not that great